# How do you remove a movieclip that is the target of a mouse event?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, actionscript

In my document class, I generate a bunch of movieclips, then position them within their own class file. What I'd like to happen is that when I touch the movieclips with the mouse, they get removed, and the score count has a one point increase. How do you remove a specific movieclip from the canvas, when it triggers a mouse event? Heres what I've tried so far, neither removeChild or removeMovieClip worked:

```
   public class Pong extends MovieClip
    {
        public var points:int=0;
        public var timer:Timer=new Timer(100);
        public function Pong()
        {
            // constructor code
            timer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, tick);
            addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER,score);
            timer.start();
        }

        public function tick(TimerEvent)
        {
            var clikBloc:clik= new clik();
            addChild(clikBloc);
        }
        public function score(evt:MouseEvent):int
        {
            trace(evt.target);
            points++;
            return (points);
            removeChild(evt.target);
            removeMovieClip(evt.target);
        }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your return is to high, so nothing bellow that is executed.

```
public function score(evt:MouseEvent):int
{
    trace(evt.target);
    points++;

    removeChild(DisplayObject(evt.target));

    // or just to be on safe side try
    // MovieClip(evt.target).parent.removeChild(evt.target)
    return (points);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for [`removeChild()`](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/display/DisplayObjectContainer.html#removeChild%28%29).

I normally create a `remove()` method within the class for the object, so that you can easily call `thing.remove();`

It would look like this:

```
public function remove():void
{
    // remove from arrays
    // remove added event listeners

    if(parent) parent.removeChild(this);
}
```

And better yet, create a base class for your visible elements which has the above `remove()` method, and then override this in extending classes so that you can remove specific listeners and so on. So assuming that the above is in a base class, this is what the override would look like in an extending class:

```
override public function remove():void
{
    removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, _click);
    super.remove();
}
```

---

Update as per comment:

You could dispatch an event from the `remove()` method and listen for it in the document class, which would let you increment the score.

```
public function remove():void
{
    // dispatch removed event
    var evt:Event = new Event("removed");
    dispatchEvent(evt);

    // remove from arrays
    // remove added event listeners

    if(parent) parent.removeChild(this);
}
```

Then when you create objects in the document class, use:

```
thing.addEventListener("removed", removed);
```

From here you can do (in the document class):

```
private function removed(e:Event):void
{
    e.target.removeEventListener("removed", removed);

    points ++;
}
```

Comment: I know you can do that from the object class, but that doesn't work in the document class, and I can't record a score within the object class. So then do I have to have the document class keep control of the score and the object class manage self deletion?